# If value exists in table 1 insert into table 2 mysql

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

For my ordering system, when an admin inserts an order i need to check if the customer he inserts for the order exists in my customer table. 
Im trying something like this, but with no luck..

```
$sql = "IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id = '$customer')
THEN insert into `order` (customer_id, product, quantity, creation_time, order_note, order_employee)
values ('$customer', '$product', '$quantity', 'now()', '$note', '$employee')";
```

Error: syntax error in first line.
What is wrong here?
And is this the right approach? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to do it "backwards" - insert if exists:

```
$sql = "insert into `order` (customer_id, product, quantity, creation_time, order_note, order_employee)
select '$customer', '$product', '$quantity', now(), '$note', '$employee'
from dual
where EXISTS(SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id = '$customer')";
```

Comment: from dual? what is that?

Comment: @MacLuc dual is "virtual table", you can only select from it, it will always returns 1 row and no columns; used in queries where you need to provide some table name but actually the table name is not needed (like in this example)

Comment: but it would still insert into 'order'?

Comment: yes, it will insert, if the condition in 'where' clause holds true

Comment: @MacLuc also, I have edited ny answer - now() should not be in quotes because it is function call returning the current date and time

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat trick you can do:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `order`
    (`customer_id`, `product`, `quantity`,
                                `creation_time`, `order_note`, `order_employee`)
    SELECT `customer_id`, '$product', '$quantity', now(), '$note', '$employee'
        FROM `customer` WHERE `customer_id`='$customer'";
```

Note that I'm trusting you have already properly sanitised your variables!

But this will only insert the order if the customer with that ID exists.

Comment: hmm, it looks like everything is coming form the customer table? is it only the customer_id it looks at?

Comment: @MacLuc Yes. That is the only actual selected column, the rest are just values. Don't worry, I've used this technique myself several times (although in my case it was for a bulk-insertion of personal messages to users matching certain criteria)

Comment: Hmm... that would suggest that there is no customer with the given ID.

Comment: the id is 1 in my test, and that is my first customer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think your problem in another way.

Proceed with steps :

1 - I need to know if customer my customer exist?

```
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM customer WHERE customer_id = '$customer'";
```

2- I try my customer, does he exist?

```
    If(!empty($result_cust)){
$sql = insert into `order` (customer_id, product, quantity, creation_time, order_note, order_employee)
values ('$customer', '$product', '$quantity', 'now()', '$note', '$employee')";
}
```

With this way your code will be more easily to understand.

> Divide and Rule

They said.

Comment: nice input, but i think its more cleaner with one sql query.